# Postgresql : Converting comma separated integer values and intervals to sequenced numbers

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table containing the following:

Value is a `varchar` type to store string characters like `comma` and `dashes` so anything goes. But typically it's contains just `numbers`, `comma` and `dash` to specify intervals.

```
id | value      | 
------------------
1  | 1,2,5,8-10 |
2  | 1,2,3      |
3  | 1-3        |
4  | 1-3, 4-5   |
5  | 1-2,2-3    |
```

I want to perform a `select` query, to retrieve the values in a "normalized" code-readable format **(comma-separated)** in database level (not in code level), that's why I need to select a table to be something like this.

```
id | value      | normalized
-------------------------------
1  | 1,2,5,8-10 |1,2,5,8,9,10
2  | 1,2,3      |1,2,3
3  | 1-3        |1,2,3
4  | 1-3, 4-5   |1,2,3,4,5
5  | 1-2,2-3    |1,2,3
```

Special case for record with id # 5, even if it specifies 2 twice, it should still only retrieve 2 once. Is there a function in `postgres` that does this already? if not how do I parse the strings and order the numbers in `Postgres sql`?

Comment: So you have a custom way of storing a set of possibly-disjoint ranges, and you want to turn that into a simple set.

Comment: yes exactly... because data is received as a simple string like that as users input it, and want to retrieve it in that way.

Comment: but you shouldn't worry how data is inputted, the code in the forms handle it. it won't ever contain strings except the comma and dash.. we allow user input like that because it is the most logical readable way of input.. for an interval let's say 330-540.. you can't really expect users to input 330,331,332...and so on..i'm a newbie in postgres and sql in general.. little help ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good case for a procedure in your preferred PL, or a simple C extension. pl/perl, pl/pythonu or pl/v8 would be my choices.

That said, it's easy enough in SQL. Split to find the subranges, which can be a single digit or a range. Then for each range generate_series over it.

e.g.:

```
SELECT n 
FROM
   regexp_split_to_table('1,2,5,8-10', ',') subrange,
   regexp_split_to_array(subrange, '-') subrange_parts,
   generate_series(subrange_parts[1]::integer, 
                  coalesce(subrange_parts[2], subrange_parts[1])::integer
   ) n;
```

which you could wrap up as a `SQL` function, or use as part of a query over a table.

Applied to a table, you get something like:

```
CREATE TABLE example
    ("id" int, "value" varchar)
;

INSERT INTO example
    ("id", "value")
VALUES
    (1, '1,2,5,8-10'),
    (2, '1,2,3'),
    (3, '1-3'),
    (4, '1-3, 4-5'),
    (5, '1-2,2-3')
;
```

When applied to a table that's something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  example.id,
  array_agg(DISTINCT n) AS expanded_set
FROM
   example,
   regexp_split_to_table(example.value, ',') subrange,
   regexp_split_to_array(subrange, '-') subrange_parts,
   generate_series(subrange_parts[1]::integer, 
                  coalesce(subrange_parts[2], subrange_parts[1])::integer
   ) n
 GROUP BY
   example.id;
```

Result (with original col added):

```
 id | original_format |  expanded_set  
----+-----------------+----------------
  1 | 1,2,5,8-10      | {1,2,5,8,9,10}
  2 | 1,2,3           | {1,2,3}
  3 | 1-3             | {1,2,3}
  4 | 1-3, 4-5        | {1,2,3,4,5}
  5 | 1-2,2-3         | {1,2,3}
(5 rows)
```

This won't be particularly fast, but it might be OK. If not, write something faster in C as an extension, or maybe plperl or something.

To understand what's going on, read the PostgreSQL manual sections on:

- `GROUP BY` and aggregation
- Aggregate functions, particularly `array_agg`
- `DISTINCT` as an aggregation qualifier
- PostgreSQL arrays, which I use here as an intermediate state and a result
- The `generate_series` function
- The `regexp_split_to_table` and `regexp_split_to_array` functions
- `LATERAL` queries, which are used implicitly here because one function consumes results from another function in the join list.

The above example will only work in PostgreSQL 9.2 and newer. If you have an older version you have to work around the lack of `LATERAL` using layers of nested subqueries.

Comment: + upvote for the really useful explanation and reading recommendations.. this will really be helpful for beginners like me :)